# Dimension of a vector space $U = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}: x-y+2z=0\}$

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $U = \{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}: x-y+2z=0\}$

My lecturer says without explanation: 'Intuitively $U$ has dimension $2$'. Can someone explain his intuition?

Comment: "hint": what are the subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with dimension 2?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: okay. what vector space(s) (over $\mathbb{R}$) do you know whose dimension is 2?

Comment: I don't know any vector spaces, I just know how to show something is a vector space and that the dimension of a vector space is the size of its basis, but here my lecturer has found the basis by using the dimension of the vector space through intuition. I want to know what intuition he used

Comment: of course you do! $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}^2$, $\mathbb{R}^3$, etc... are all vector spaces (vector spaces are _inspired_ on those). and $\mathbb{R}$ has dimension 1, $\mathbb{R}^2$ has dimension 2, and so on. i think perhaps you need to learn some more linear algebra before you can comprehend easily the intuitive sense of it?

Comment: basically, what you have over there is a plan of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that crosses the origin so basically the plan is just a "copy" of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and therefore has dimension 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map
$$f\colon \Bbb R^3\rightarrow \Bbb R,\quad (x,y,z)\mapsto x-y+2z$$
is a non zero linear form so
$$U=\ker f$$
is an hyper-plan of $\Bbb R^3$ so $\dim U=2$.

**Edit:** We can find the dimension of $U$ using this geometric method which's pretty intuitive:

First notice that $U$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ so its dimension is less or equal $2$ (*clearly $U\ne\Bbb R^3$*). Moreover:

- the intersection of $U$ with $x-y$ plane i.e. the plane $\{z=0\}$ is 
  $$\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\;:\; x=y\}$$
  which is a line and
- the intersection of $U$ with $x-z$ plane i.e. the plane $\{y=0\}$ is 
  $$\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3\;:\; x=-2z\}$$
  which is also a line so $U$ contains two non identical lines hence $U$ is a plane and its dimension is $2$.

Comment: And now can you explain this in a way a first year could understand rather than someone who has been studying mathematics for however many years. Thanks

Comment: In your first year do you study the linear transformation, its kernel and its image and the rank nullity theorem?

Comment: Nope, I just know how to show something is a vector space and that the dimension of a vector space is the size of its basis, but here my lecturer has found the basis by using the dimension of the vector space through intuition. I want to know what intuition he used

Comment: I edited my answer. @user2850514

Answer (score 2):

The intuition behind is you have three variables combinated linearly so one of them is combination of the other two therefore you have two "degrees of freedom"

$$(x,y,z)=\left(x,y,\frac{y-x}{2}\right)$$
$$(x,y,z)=x\left(1,0,\frac{-1}{2}\right)+y\left(0,1,\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Then all the $(x,y,z) \in U$ are linear combination of $\left(1,0,\frac{-1}{2}\right)$ and $\left(0,1,\frac{1}{2}\right)$ and since they  are independent the dimension is $
2$.

Comment: This is the method I usually use but my lecturer said 'Intuitively the dimension is 2', without doing this. I want to know how he knows this?

Comment: @user2850514 see my edit please.